# publishing portal or collaboration portal

Tags: 2007, windows-server

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 on Windows Server 2008. If there is an existing web site, how to tell whether it is built from collaboration portal template or publishing portal template quickly?

regards,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Forum/determine-site-template-site-11323.aspx

> The site definition used when building
>   a site isn't available anywhere in the
>   user interface. The only other way to
>   get the underlying site definition,
>   without writing code, would be to do
>   the following:
>
> 1. Save the site as a template
> 2. Download the template to your local harddrive
> 3. Change the extension from .stp to .cab (the .stp is a normal compressed
>      cabinet file)
> 4. Open the .cab file and extract the manifest.xml file to your hard drive
> 5. Open the manifest.xml file in an editor and find the TemplateID and
>      Configuration elements. These
>      reference a specific site definition
>      value listed in one of the Webtemp.xml
>      files stored in the 12 hive at
>      template/1033/xml.
>
> Personally, I find it easier to write
>   a quick command line utility program.
>   Again, these values will only give you
>   the base site definition from which
>   the site was built, not the site
>   template if one was used. There is no
>   way that I know of to get the site
>   template (.STP) file used to create an
>   existing site.

More details [can be found here](http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Forum/determine-site-template-site-11323.aspx) and [here](http://blog.rafelo.com/2008/05/determining-site-template-used-on.html).

Comment: Could we easily find whether it is collaboration portal or publishing portal from Web interface?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to check the content DB if you have access. In the Webs table find the site using the url (FullUrl) or the title (Title) and then check the WebTemplate column and the ProvisionConfig column, then check the {SharePoint Root}\TEMPLATE\1033\xml for the correct site definition.

*Do not fiddle with the DB, just look at the table - now I said it...*

Comment: Could we easily find whether it is collaboration portal or publishing portal from Web interface?

Comment: The web interface does not provide you with that information. It might even be a custom site def.